# Why this perl script with strange variable names works?

Tags: perl, unicode

What I read in perl doc the perl identifier should be an `word character`. (Not counting special perl variables).

Somewhere on the net I saw this example script:

```
use 5.018;
use utf8;

my($ , $ , $ , $ ) = (1..4);
say "$ " if( $ + $  == $ );
```

And it works without any error. So, perl allows some "bone and arrow like" characters as variable names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that matches `\p{Word}` can be used in an identifier name in Perl. The Unicode standard defines quite a large number of characters with that property.

The `use utf8` pragma is important; that tells Perl that the source file itself is encoded in UTF-8, so those characters can appear as literals in the code.

As an example, one of the characters in your code is [LINEAR B IDEOGRAM B254 DART](http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B100d8). The Unicode character database says this is a "letter, other" which is included in the set of Word characters.

Answer (score 2):

The characters in that example are all of the Lo (Letter, Other) category. Perl considers these valid word characters:

```
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));
print grep { /\w/ } ("\x{100af}", "\x{10082}", "\x{100d8}", "\x{100ae}");
```

Comment: friedo's answer is probably more accurate--`\w`'s behavior is locale-dependent, while `\p{Word}` explicitly matches the unicode property.

Comment: `\w` is not locale-dependent unless you use `use locale;`